# Fix JSON keys in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-10

I want to fix or validate keys for JSON object in PostgreSQL(v10.7).

For instance, I have a JSON object called **service_config** which looks like;

`{"con_type": "Foo", "capacity": 2, "capacity_unit": "gbps"}`

And I have table:

```
 id(serial)   service_name(char)   service_type(char)    service_config(JSON)
-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------
    1      |          com        |        ethernet     | {"con_type": "ddc", "capacity": 2, "capacity_unit": "gbps"}
    2      |          res        |        gpon         | {"con_type": "ftth", "capacity": 1, "capacity_unit": "gbps"}
```

Now, whenever I insert row into the table, I want to make sure or validate that the **service_config** column contains all the keys that are mentioned above, no more, no less. However, there could be null value for the keys.

Is this possible in Postgres and/or is there any better way to do this?

**Possible solutions**:

1- Validate service_config at the backend API and make sure all the keys are there. (currently in place and working)

2- Write a function in Postgres to validate service_config on insert and update. (doable but tedious)

**Limitation**: I cannot add any extension in Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to make sure or validate that the service_config column contains all the keys that are mentioned above, no more, no less. However, there could be null value for the keys.

Turn them into columns.

JSON is nice when you need to just dump some data into a row and you're not sure what it's going to be. Now that you are sure what it's going to be, and you want more constraints, that's what columns do best.

```
alter table whatever add column con_type text;
alter table whatever add column capacity integer;
alter table whatever add column capacity_unit text;

update whatever set
  con_type = data->'con_type',
  capacity = data->'capacity',
  capacity_unit = data->'capacity_unit';

alter table whatever drop column data
```

The columns will always be there. Their values may be null. You can add per-column `check` constraints and indexes. No additional validations are necessary.

If you still need json, use [`jsonb_build_object`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE).

```
select
  jsonb_build_object(
    'con_type', con_type,
    'capacity', capacity,
    'capacity_unit', capacity_unit
  )
from whatever;
```

And, if you need it for compatibility purposes, you can make this a view.

```
create view whatever_as_json
select
  *,
  jsonb_build_object(
    'con_type', con_type,
    'capacity', capacity,
    'capacity_unit', capacity_unit
  ) as data
from whatever;
```

---

Note that I use `text`, not `char`, because there is no advantage to `char` in Postgres. See the tip in [8.3. Character Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-character.html)

> There is no performance difference among these three types, apart from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type, and a few extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a length-constrained column. While character(n) has performance advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage in PostgreSQL; in fact character(n) is usually the slowest of the three because of its additional storage costs. ***In most situations text or character varying should be used instead.***

Comment: The reason for using JSON and not having columns is the unstructured nature of the data. For instance, there could be several services that have different capacity_unit. There are other example too where same field can have different data types (or at least represented in different data type).

Comment: @Myz "*For instance, there could be several services that have different capacity_unit.*" Sorry, I don't follow what that means. As for different data types, if they're simply different representations, normalizing them on insert would make the data easier to work with. For example, `"capacity": 1` and `"capacity": "1"` should both be normalized to the integer `1`. This will make the data easier to work with, index, and ensure it is correct. Showing us some examples would help.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear. What I meant by different is that some services can have _capacity_unit_ as "mbps" or "gbps" or sometimes even "kW" or "sq-meter". That is not a big issue as data type of _capacity_unit_ is _char_. A little trickier situation is with the field _capacity_ as it could be either 5 or "5/5". To solve this, I could just use _char_ and then parse it to _int_ where necessary.

Comment: @Myz Yes, you can store them as ***text*** (again, avoid char) but that has consequences for ease of use and indexing. I can't figure what "5/5" means with any of those units, unless it just means 1, so I'd encourage you to pursue further normalization. Perhaps you need another column?

Comment: Instead of writing upload and download capacity separately (in separate columns), it is written as 5/5. So 5/5 means 5 gbps of upload capacity and 5gbps of download capacity. By the way, it is not symmetric, i.e. it could also be 8/10 or 1/8 etc. Regarding further normalization, combining unstructured data into JSON seems to be the appropriate option due to the project requirements.

Comment: @Myz I would suggest normalizing that to numeric upload and download capacity columns. Then it can be indexed and efficiently queried. With "8/10" you need to scan and parse every row making queries slow and error prone.